# Is it possible fo brick an STM32 board through some wrong configurations in STMCubeIDE during burning/debugging?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, openocd, stm32f1, st-link

I have been using my STM32 Blue Pill with GCC Cross Platform tools with no problem. I used ARM assembly to write a blink program, connected the blue pill to ST-LinkV2 using SWD and connected the ST-LinkV2 to my computer. On my computer, I use command line gcc assembler, linker and OpenOCD...The LED blinks. I also use STLink toolset (st-flash, st-info, etc) to communicate with the Blue Pill and it works. Then I decided to migrate to STMCubeIDE so as to get familiar with STM HAL. I create a blink project in STMCubeIDE, I program the chip, it runs the first time, but fails to connect to the chip the second time. I try to access the chip using gcc tools and STlink tools, no success - but initial blink keeps running on the chip that is refusing connection. I get a second Blue Pill board, I can connect to it using gcc tools and STlink - and I can program it using st-flash or using OpenOCD, I try to program it using the same STMCubeIDE code, it's programmed the first time and also refuses connection thereafter...refusing connection using gcc or STlink but still blinking the original blink from the first STMCubeIDE program. It says "Failed to parse flash type or unrecognized flash type". I have three more Blue Pills and I don't know if the STMCubeIDE blink code is bricking my Blue Pills.
Is it possible for some programming/debugging configurations in STMCubeIDE to brick an MCU (Blue Pill)? Thank you in advance for any information.

I tried a different computer with its gcc tools and STLink software but cannot still connect to the Blue Pills that developed problems. I tried to connect to the Blue Pills using STMCubeIDE on another computer and still no success.

Comment: Try using STM32CubeProgrammer. It gives you more information about the connected board, and lets you read the flash and/or registers etc. There is a register you can set that permanently disables debugging / modifying the flash, but you'd have to deliberately set it.

Comment: Check whether you're accidentally resetting the debugging pins on the device. Pretty easy to do this when settings up other pins on the same GPIO port.
I don't recognise that error text though, so it might not be this.